# Highchart connector custom style

Tags: graph, highcharts, pie-chart

I want to create doughnut chart using highcharts like below:
[image]

Please help me to create. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using `attr` method you can set `stroke-dasharray` property for connectors:

```
chart: {
    ...,
    events: {
        load: function() {
            var points = this.series[0].points;

            points.forEach(function(p) {
                p.connector.attr({
                    'stroke-dasharray': "4, 4"
                });
            });
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/boxhv0yt/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SeriesPieDataLabelsOptionsObject#connectorShape

**Docs:** https://www.highcharts.com/docs/advanced-chart-features/pie-datalabels-alignment

Comment: Thanks @ppotaczek for the dashed connector. 
What about to place data-labels one at the edge of connector and another close to pie chart (Please refer the image).
Also is there any way make connector line horizontal. 
If you could include these in the fiddle it will be great help.

Comment: To make connector line horizontal use `connectorShape` function. To add additional `dataLabels` use `Highcharts.SVGRenderer` class or add an additional series: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/jbtpfL2o/

Comment: Can you suggest some tutorials where M and L in **path** explained and how to manipulate the points.

Comment: Hi @Tapas Mahato, You can check this basic tutorial: https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/svg_path.asp